# How to apply google maps api in laravel livewire

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am using laravel livewire for my website and on that web, I created a multi-step form where I have to fetch google maps API in the first step. as I know I have to use wire: ignore when using third-party JavaScript library in Livewire component. but the problem comes when I switch from form step 2 to step 1, where google map is not rendered

This is my livewire view.

```
<div wire:ignore>
    <div id="address-map-container" class="mt-2" style="width:100%;height:320px; ">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="address-map"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End Google Maps -->

<!-- Seach in google maps -->
<input type="text" wire:model.lazy="address_address" id="address-input"
       class="mt-4 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md map-input"
       placeholder="Search in Google Maps">
<input type="hidden" wire:model.lazy="address_latitude" id="address-latitude" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" wire:model.lazy="address_longitude" id="address-longitude" value="0" />
<!-- End in Seach google maps -->
```

This is my javascript code.

```
 <script>
         function initialize() {
         $('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
             var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
             if (keyCode === 13) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 return false;
             }
         });
         const locationInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("map-input");

         const autocompletes = [];
         const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
         for (let i = 0; i < locationInputs.length; i++) {

             const input = locationInputs[i];
             const fieldKey = input.id.replace("-input", "");
             const isEdit = document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-latitude").value != '' && document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-longitude").value != '';

             const latitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-latitude").value) || -6.251855;
             const longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-longitude").value) || 106.978942;

             const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(fieldKey + '-map'), {
                 center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
                 zoom: 15
             });
             const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
             });

             marker.setVisible(isEdit);

             const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
             autocomplete.key = fieldKey;
             autocompletes.push({input: input, map: map, marker: marker, autocomplete: autocomplete});
         }

         for (let i = 0; i < autocompletes.length; i++) {
             const input = autocompletes[i].input;
             const autocomplete = autocompletes[i].autocomplete;
             const map = autocompletes[i].map;
             const marker = autocompletes[i].marker;

             google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                 marker.setVisible(false);
                 const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                 geocoder.geocode({'placeId': place.place_id}, function (results, status) {
                     if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                         const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                         const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                         setLocationCoordinates(autocomplete.key, lat, lng);
                     }
                 });

                 if (!place.geometry) {
                     window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                     input.value = "";
                     return;
                 }

                 if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                     map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                 } else {
                     map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                     map.setZoom(17);
                 }
                 marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                 marker.setVisible(true);

             });
         }
     }

     function setLocationCoordinates(key, lat, lng) {
         const latitudeField = document.getElementById(key + "-" + "latitude");
         const longitudeField = document.getElementById(key + "-" + "longitude");
         latitudeField.value = lat;
         longitudeField.value = lng;
         Livewire.emit('lat')
     }
```

And this is my livewire controller

```
  // Form properties
    public $currentPage = 1;
    public $property_name;
    public $address_address;
    public $postal_code;
    public $property_phone_number;
    public $number_of_rooms;


    public $pages = [
        1 => [
            'heading' => 'General Information',
            'subheading' => 'Enter',
        ],
        2 => [
            'heading' => 'Property Detail',
            'subheading' => 'Enter',
        ],
    ];

    private $validationRules = [
        1 => [
            'property_name' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'address_address' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'postal_code' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'property_phone_number' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'number_of_rooms' => ['required'],
        ],
        2 => [
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'confirmPassword' => ['required', 'string', 'same:password', 'min:8'],
        ],
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName, $this->validationRules[$this->currentPage]);
    }

    public function goToNextPage()
    {

        $this->currentPage++;
    }

    public function goToPreviousPage()
    {
        $this->currentPage--;
    }
```

Can someone help me how to emit the google maps API and listen to it in JavaScript, therefore, google maps will always be rendered? Thanks